# How to create a new action in popup menu [eclipse]

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-luna

I want to create a new action inside a popup menu ,which will be shown for only xml files.
I'd like also to know how to enable that action in package explorer view.
P.S,
I have already written the java code for the action and tried the template plugin project , but I can see it only in navigation view and on every file.

Comment: Look at the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` for modern command / handler based menu items or `org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus` for deprecated action based menu items.

Comment: action based menu items are deprecated ?

Comment: Look at the help for the `org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus` extension point, it says deprecated several times. `org.eclipse.ui.menus` has been recommended for a long time, although there is still a lot of code using actions.